# Parse through rotation choices to produce class schedules

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop

I have a [Sheets project](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ki0Cya3IWNwdLIBe0fR1vwfz_ansmfa52NilmdFBrd0/edit?usp=sharing) with 6 worksheets. I'm using student choices to generate a series of 4 rotations in which students can visit classes.

- `Form Responses 1` lists names in Column D; Columns I-N list a set of six possible rotation choices
- `6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, `6Rot3`, and `6Rot4` correspond to each of the four possible rotations
- `mainRoster6` is a master roster produced to reflect names and rotation choices

I'm trying to parse through `Form Responses 1`, with the following conditions:

- Start by looking at Column I and see if there are "open spots" (<47) in the corresponding column of `6Rot1`. If so, add the name to that column. Otherwise, check `6Rot2` and try to perform the same operation. Etc., until all 4 rotations have been checked.
- If there are no open spots in either of the 4 rotations, then check Column J and try to fit the student in the correct class's name, etc.

The intention is to assign the student's top unique choices to 4 rotations. If a student has already chosen a class for one rotation, then that class should not appear again in a different rotation.

I'm trying to solve two bugs:

- If a class has already been added for a student for a rotation, he should not have the same class in a newer rotation (I tried to solve this in lines 62-67 but it didn't work). In the example sheet, for the student in row 3, once the student has been placed in "Spanish I" for rotation 2, it should skip his third choice (a repeated "Spanish I" and proceed trying to place him in "Coding" for his third rotation.
- The program should assign in rotations in the order of preference (first, then second, then third, etc.). Right now, if a rotation is full for a specific class, it simply ignores that class (even if the next rotation may be available) and moves on to the next choice. In the example sheet, the first student has "coding" as third choice. Although that class is not available in the 3rd rotation, it's available in the 4th rotation. The program should try to place coding in the 4th rotation and then look at the fourth choice and try to place the student into any available rotation (in this case, rotation 3 would be available).

This is what I have currently:

```
function myFunction() {
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ki0Cya3IWNwdLIBe0fR1vwfz_ansmfa52NilmdFBrd0');
  var firstRotation = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6Rot1');
  var secondRotation = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6Rot2'); 
  var thirdRotation = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6Rot3');
  var fourthRotation = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6Rot4'); 

  var mainRoster = mainSheet.getSheetByName('mainRoster6');
  var responsesSheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var destinationCell;
  var column;
  var columnValues;
  var columnContainsStudent;
  var currentSheet;
  var mainRosterLastRow;
  var studentName;
  var compassTeacher;
  var classChoice;
  var rotationCounter;
  var choicesCounter;
  var successCounter; 

  var rotationOneSuccess;
  var rotationTwoSuccess;
  var rotationThreeSuccess;
  var rotationFourSuccess;

  var responsesLastRow = responsesSheet.getLastRow();

  var currentRotationsArray;

//  var y;
  var z;
  for (z = 2; z < responsesLastRow + 1; z++) {
    studentName = responsesSheet.getRange(z, 4).getValues();
    mainRoster.getRange(z, 2).setValue(studentName);

    compassTeacher = responsesSheet.getRange(z, 6).getValues();
    mainRoster.getRange(z, 1).setValue(compassTeacher);

    choicesCounter = 1;
    successCounter = 0;
    rotationCounter = 1; 

    rotationOneSuccess = false;
    rotationTwoSuccess = false;
    rotationThreeSuccess = false;
    rotationFourSuccess = false;

    while (choicesCounter < 7) {

      if (successCounter > 4) {
        break;
      }

      classChoice = responsesSheet.getRange(z, 8 + choicesCounter).getValues();

      //test for includes in previous choices
      var currentRotationsArray = mainRoster.getRange(z, 4, 1, 4).getValues();

//      for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
//       if (currentRotationsArray[0][y] == classChoice) {
//         choicesCounter++;
//         break;
//       }
//      }

      while (successCounter < 4) {

        if (rotationOneSuccess == false) {
          currentSheet = firstRotation;
        } else if (rotationTwoSuccess == false) {
          currentSheet = secondRotation;
        } else if (rotationThreeSuccess == false) {
          currentSheet = thirdRotation;
        } else {
          currentSheet = fourthRotation;
        }

        // Set column number and get values as an array, depending on class choice
        if (classChoice == "Guitar 7") {
          column = 1;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Communications - Video Production") {
          column = 2;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Communications - Journalism") {
          column = 3;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Coding") {
          column = 4;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Art 7") {
          column = 5;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Latin I") {
          column = 6;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("F1:F").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "Spanish I") {
          column = 7;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("G1:G").getValues();
        } else if (classChoice == "French I") {
          column = 8;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("H1:H").getValues();
        } else {
          column = 9;
          columnValues = currentSheet.getRange("I1:I").getValues();
        }

        // Find column's current last row
        var columnLength = columnValues.filter(String).length;

        //Add the student to the class's rotation, if the student isn't already there and there's >46 people already in
        if (columnLength < 48) {
          for(var n in columnValues){
            if(columnValues[n][0] == studentName){
              columnContainsStudent = true;
              rotationCounter++;
              break;
            } 
          }

          if (columnContainsStudent != true) {
            destinationCell = currentSheet.getRange(columnLength + 1, column);
            destinationCell.setValue(studentName);

            if (currentSheet == firstRotation) {
              rotationOneSuccess = true;
            } else if (currentSheet == secondRotation) {
              rotationTwoSuccess = true;
            } else if (currentSheet == thirdRotation) {
              rotationThreeSuccess = true;
            } else {
              rotationFourSuccess = true;
            }

            mainRoster.getRange(z, rotationCounter + 3).setValue(classChoice);

            successCounter++;
            rotationCounter++;
            break;
          }  

        rotationCounter++; 
        } else { 
          break
        }

        rotationCounter++;
      }

      choicesCounter++;

    } 
  }

}
```

If you look at the linked sample spreadsheet, the logic is as follows:

- We're looking at `Form Responses 1` row by row, with the intention of adding 4 "choices" for that person in 4 rotations (`6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, etc.). Columns I-N list 6 possible choices, but ideally I want to put the student in his top 4 choices.
- I want the program to first look at `Form Responses 1` Column I. In the sample sheet it's "Guitar 7". Then the program should look at `6Rot1` and see if the column for "Guitar 7" (Column A) has any open spaces (i.e. if it has less than 48 rows already filled). In the sample sheet, there are 36 "Placeholder Names" so it adds the first student to the first blank row in Column A (row 37). Once the name has been added to one of the rotations, `mainRoster6` reflects that same information (column D in this case reflects "Guitar 7", which contains the same information for `6Rot1`).
- The program should next look back at `Form Responses 1` and consider the student's next choice: in this case it would be the "second choice" (column J, "French I"). I want to look at the first possible rotation (`6Rot1`, 6Rot2`, etc) that doesn't include the student AND has less than 48 people already in it, so that we can put his choice there. In this case`6Rot2`had already 39 names in it, so it accepted the student into row 40 of column H. After adding the student name in`6Rot2`, the program adds "French I" to Column E of`mainRoster6` ("Rotation 2")
- It next looks back at `Form Responses 1` and consider the "third choice" in column K, and repeats the process.
- If a class is already "full" (has more than 47 names listed already in the column), then the program should try to find the first available rotation. For example, the student in `Form Responses 1` has "Coding" as his third choice. `6Rot3` already has no space for column D ("Coding"), so it should first try to add the student's name ("Billy Kid") in Column D of `6Rot4` and then try to put in the student's name in column I of `6Rot3` for "German I".
- What I'm trying to do with the code is parsing row by row of `Form Responses 1` and putting the first 4 possible "choices" into the 4 possible rotations, and having `mainRoster6` reflect that same information as a kind of abbreviated master list.
- If a student lists two or more similar choices in `Form Responses 1` columns I-N, then the program should ignore the repeated values. For example, in row 3 of `Form Responses 1` it should overlook the second "Spanish" in K3 and move on to the next choice for that student.
- If there are no more possible choices or rotations that can account for that choice, then the space can be left blank (see for example `Form Responses 1` row 4: based on the student's choices and available spots, we were only able to honor the first three choices ("French" was already filled completely in `6Rot4`; "Latin I" and "Art 7" were already in the schedule).

Under these conditions, I would have expected `mainRoster6` to have this intended output:
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal. 1. What is `"open spots" (<47)`? 2. What is `J` of `If there are no open spots in either of the 4 rotations, then check Column J`? 3. In your shared Spreadsheet, several names of `Full Name` at the column "D" on `Form Responses 1` are put in one row. When the name is duplicated, how will do this? 4. Where can we see the input and output you expect in your shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. 1. "Open spots" means that the column has 46 or less items (e.g. Col C in `6Rot1` has only a header, so it has 45 open spots; Col F in the same worksheet has 48 items already, so it doesn't have any open spots). 2. The algorithm I want to produce first checks Col I ("First choice") of `Form Responses 1` and tries to put that class in the first available rotation; the program then loops to try to place the first 4 possible choices from columns J-N, until all 4 rotations have been reached. 4. `Form Responses 1` mimics the input I'll be using for this; the other...

Comment: The other worksheets constitute the output. What I'm trying to do with each row of `Form Responses 1` is to place the person's class "choices" into four rotations (`6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, etc). The outer `for loop` in my code is reading `Form Responses 1` line by line, trying to put the first 4 possible "choices" into the 4 rotations. `mainRoster6` simply reflects the same information from the 4 rotation worksheets (`6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, etc). Since I want all 4 rotations to have different classes, I've identified the bugs listed above :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your goal. The sample input values are the sheet of `Form Responses 1`. The sample output values are `mainRoster6`, `6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, `6Rot3`, `6Rot4`. If my understanding is correct, in your shared Spreadsheet, several names of `Full Name` at the column "D" on Form Responses 1 are put in one row in the sheets `6Rot1`, `6Rot2`, `6Rot3`, `6Rot4`, respectively. I cannot understand about this logic. And when the name is duplicated, how will do this?

Comment: By the way, where can I see the input and output you expect in your shared Spreadsheet? For example, in your current Spreadsheet, the values of cells "J2:N2" in `Form Responses 1` are `French I,Coding,German I,Art 7,Communications - Video Production`. In this case, "B2" and "E2" of "6Rot1" are "Joe Smith" and "Peter Salt". "G2" and "I2" of "6Rot2" are "Joe Smith" and "Peter Salt". "G2" and "I2" of "6Rot3" are "Joe Smith" and "Billy Kid". "B2" and "D2" of "6Rot1" are "Billy Kid" and "Joe Smith". I cannot understand about this logic. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the question to clarify the logic of the program after the code. I'm working mainly with two while loops to parse through `Form Responses 1` to produce a schedule of rotations. Every student is supposed to have 4 different rotations, based on either his top four rotation class choices (ideally) out of six choices that the student proposed. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your explanation of the logic, the sheets from `6Rot1` to `6Rot4` are used. But in your shared Spreadsheet, there are "Fifth choice" and "Sixth choice". How about this? And I cannot understand about the last 4 options in your additional list. The reason that I cannot understand about your question is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Although there are 4 rotations (`6Rot1` to `6Rot4`) for the schedule, I've given students the option to list 6 choices. If one or two of their top 4 choices is either full, or they wrote the same choice twice, then I want the program to check their fifth and sixth choices. This way, the program matches the student with either the top 4 choices if possible but has some other options if that is not possible :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still understand about your logic for achieving your goal. I deeply apologize for this. When you can give me a time to think of it, I'm glad. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding.